# Array rotation to the left (recursive)

Tags: c, arrays, function, recursion, definition

Disclaimer: it is an exercise, but it's not homework.

Now, here we go. The exercise asks for the rotation of a generic array to the left, putting the first element in the last position, and doing it so with recursion. My thoughts:

Here's the right rotation one I've written:

```
 void moveArrayRight (int array[], int dim){
            if(dim!=1){
                int holder;
                holder = array[dim-1];
                array[dim-1]=array[dim-2];
                array[dim-2]=holder;
                moveArrayRight(array, dim-1);
            }
 }
```

The thing is: I cannot (I think) use the same technique for the left one. I *could* add another parameter (technically, I could use whatever I want to), but I deeply dislike it. If possible, I would like to retain only two parameters. I also thought of doing something like using the last element of the array to store what is going to be in the next cell, but I don't know how to implement it mainly for a reason: I have no idea how to retain the original dimension of the array.

Any thoughts, hints or something like that?

Comment: Why recusrsion? A loop seems simler. And you could use memmove() ...

Comment: Definitely so. But the exercise asks for recursion. I suppose it's just to do a bit of practice with recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void rotate_left( int a[], size_t n )
{
   if ( n > 1 )
   {
      int tmp = a[0];
      a[0] = a[1];
      a[1] = tmp;
      rotate_left( a + 1, n - 1 );
   }
}
```

Here is an example of the function usage

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rotate_left( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n > 1 )
    {
        int tmp = a[0];
        a[0] = a[1];
        a[1] = tmp;
        rotate_left( a + 1, n - 1 );
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    puts( "" );

    rotate_left( a, 5 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    puts( "" );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 1
```

Comment: Oooooh thank you! I had no idea you could use something like "a+1" on arrays!

Comment: @Gennaro Marco Devincenzis When an array is passed to a function it is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

To use recursion effectively you would split the work, for example in the middle, instead of just slicing off one item at a time. Something like:

```
function shiftLeft(arr, start, len, in) {
  var result;
  if (len == 1) {
    result = arr[start];
    arr[start] = in;
  } else {
    var half = Math.floor(len / 2);
    in = shiftLeft(arr, start + half, len - half, in);
    result = shiftLeft(arr, start, half, in);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
shiftLeft(arr, 0, arr.length, arr[0]);
```

(Disclaimer: The code is not tested and might have bugs, I wrote this on my phone.)